# GUI Extension, Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined

Tags: 2013-sp1, gui-extensions, content-manager

We are trying to write a GUI extension to showcase some information to the Editor. For this we show a popup with the required information to the editor, unfortanetly we are unable to add some buttons, our code looks like as followed;

```
var options = {};
options.className = "question";
options.popupType = $popupManager.Type.MESSAGE_BOX;
options.title = "This is a popup!";

var btnConfirm = {action: "confirm", label: "Yes", showInPanel: false, showInPopup: true};
var btnCancel = {action: "cancel", label: "No", showInPanel: false, showInPopup: true};

options.buttons = [btnConfirm, btnCancel];

var popup = $popupManager.createExternalContentPopup(null, $cme.Popups.MESSAGE_DETAILS.FEATURES, options);
$evt.addEventHandler(popup, "confirm", onCopyConflictPopupSubmit);
$evt.addEventHandler(popup, "cancel", onCopyConflictPopupClosed);
popup.open();
```

Without adding the `options.buttons` we get the popup with a close button. Looking in `MessageBoxPopup.js` we see that we can add buttons like above. But when we do that we get below error; Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined
>       at Tridion.Controls.MessageBoxPopup.focus (coreresource_v7.1.0.66.43_.js?sav=1&cnt=core:59)
>       at a (coreresource_v7.1.0.66.43_.js?sav=1&cnt=core:55)
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined
>       at Tridion.Controls.MessageBoxPopup.focus (coreresource_v7.1.0.66.43_.js?sav=1&cnt=core:59)
>       at Tridion.Controls.MessageBoxPopup.Tridion.Controls.BaseModalPopup._handleFocusOutside (coreresource_v7.1.0.66.43_.js?sav=1&cnt=core:56)
>       at Tridion.Controls.FocusOutsideMonitor. (coreresource_v7.1.0.66.43_.js?sav=1&cnt=core:1)
>       at Tridion.EventRegisterClass.f.executeListener (coreresource_v7.1.0.66.43_.js?sav=1&cnt=core:14)
>       at Tridion.Controls.FocusOutsideMonitor.a (coreresource_v7.1.0.66.43_.js?sav=1&cnt=core:14)
>       at Tridion.Controls.FocusOutsideMonitor.Tridion.ObjectWithEvents.processHandlers (coreresource_v7.1.0.66.43_.js?sav=1&cnt=core:12)
>       at Tridion.Controls.FocusOutsideMonitor.Tridion.ObjectWithEvents.fireEvent (coreresource_v7.1.0.66.43_.js?sav=1&cnt=core:12)
>       at Tridion.Controls.FocusOutsideMonitor._doFocusOut (coreresource_v7.1.0.66.43_.js?sav=1&cnt=core:50)
>       at Tridion.Controls.FocusOutsideMonitor.a (coreresource_v7.1.0.66.43_.js?sav=1&cnt=core:50)
>       at coreresource_v7.1.0.66.43_.js?sav=1&cnt=core:1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this way of creating popups the only event that seems to emit on clicking the buttons is a `dialog_closed` event. In that event you recieve an `Tridion.Core.Event` object with the clicked button information such as the action property.

So you could do something like:

```js
$evt.addEventHandler(popup, "dialog_closed", handleButtonActions);
```

And handle the actions you want inside `handleButtonActions` function.

The only reason I see to create a popup like this it's because you want a simple popup to get some sort of explicit confirmation before an action. If you want to give it more functionality and/or be able to handle events like you are trying to, you should create your own popup view.

Comment: but (assuming) it goes through MessageBoxPopup.js ,,, in the _buildMessageBox function is does a check for buttons. If there is no buttons it adds a close button. But i assume it goes through the loop and creates the custom buttons?

Comment: That's true. It creates the buttons you tell it to create.

But the only event they will fire will be `dialog_closed`. You can check that through `_addEventHandlers` it adds `_handleButtonClick` as the only click listener for all buttons, and that function only emits `dialog_closed` events.

I only found references to this popup on the MessageCenter and UserInfoBar so it looks like MessageBoxPopup it's intended to be used only with simple confirmations for messages because at some point `actions` will be used to fire events with `$messages.executeAction`.